# CPQ Javascript Calculator - Console.Log

Tags: javascript, cpq

I am working with the CPQ JavaScript Calculator. How do you see the debug logs? I mean it is running through as a Custom Script Record when running the CPQ UI. I looked through the pages with the Chrome debugging Tool but I am not seeing the Console.log outputs anywhere. I can see where it is calling the custom script but not the code.

```
export function onAfterCalculate(quote, lines, conn) {
 console.log('onAfterCalculate 4');
 return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it easiest to add `debugger;` statements where I want to check out what my code is doing. If you open developer tools before clicking "Calculate", your browser will put a break point on that line. This lets you inspect values, etc.

```
export function onAfterCalculate(quote, lines, conn) {
 console.log('onAfterCalculate 4');
 debugger;
 return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Comment: hmm, I just tried that. It doesnt seem to work. I added the debugger; statement - control Shit I before calculate but it is not adding the break point to inspect.

Comment: it works in w3 school - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_state_debugger but does not work for some reason while in Salesforce

Comment: @CodeMonger you sure you configured CPQ to use that particular Custom Script record in the package configuration?

Comment: Opps no Dan was correct. I made a mistake.